# Footnote without numbering and without indention in beamer class

Tags: beamer, numbering, footnotes, indentation

I am trying to generate a footnote without numbering AND without indention in the first footnote line when using the beamer class. My MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\myfootnote}[1]{
    \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{}
    \footnotetext{\scriptsize#1}
    \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
}

\begin{document}
    \frame{
        Body Text 
        \myfootnote{\blindtext}
    }           
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

However, when trying to remove the indention with e.g.

```
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
```

which has been proposed in another thread the complete footnote disappears. Using the article class works just fine.

Comment: Footnotes without markers are quite ... useless, they can be overlooked. In addition -- how much footnote content is useful at all for a beamer frame?

Comment: Thank your for your comment, I just want to include a literature reference which has just two lines and thought a footnote is appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the extra space with a negative `\hspace` as in `\footnotetext{\hspace{-16.5pt}\scriptsize#1}`. The space `-16.5pt` is found by iteration, and might have to change for different templates.

I often try to have all extra things on a beamer page independent of the main text. So I would like a footnote to be placed without affecting the main text. This can be done by placing it using `tikz` and the coordinate `current page`. In my opinion, it looks better for shorter footnotes like references and some other things. (The case with `\blindtext` is too long and should probably not be used as a footnote). If you have more than one footnote on a frame you need to write them in the same command, since otherwise they will end up on top of each other. But on a beamer frame I don't thing that is a problem.

BTW I changed your `\frame{...}` to `\begin{frame}...\end{frame}`.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\myfootnote}[1]{
    \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{}
    \footnotetext{\hspace{-16.5pt}\scriptsize#1}
    \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
}
\newcommand\alternativefootnote[1]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw (current page.south west) +(1in + \oddsidemargin,0.5em)
  node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt]{\parbox{\textwidth}{%
      \rlap{\rule{10em}{0.4pt}}\raggedright\scriptsize#1}};}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test of footnote 1}
  Body Text 
  \myfootnote{\blindtext}  
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test of footnote 2}
  Body Text 
  \alternativefootnote{\blindtext}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where did you get the width `\hspace{-16.5pt}` from? Is it something like a `parskip`?

Comment: It was found by testing.